# How to specify RESTful request parameters in UriBuilder.fromUri?

Tags: java, api, rest, rest-client

I am new to RESTful webservices. I am trying to get a JSON file from a RESTful web service of RIPE Atlas. The URL of the API is https://stat.ripe.net/data/abuse-contact-finder/data.json?resource=193/23. Please find my code below for retrieving the JSON file:

```
      WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("https://stat.ripe.net/data/abuse-contact-finder/data.json").build());
      // getting JSON data
      System.out.println(service.path("resource=193/23").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
```

In this above case, I am getting 400 Bad request from the server. When i gave the complete URL, along with the request parameter "?resource=193/23" in 'fromUri', it is working fine. But when I specified the request parameter in the 'service.path' like above, it is not. What am I doing wrong? I am sure this is a silly question, forgive my ignorance, but could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add the query param differently.

```
 service.queryParam("resource","193/23").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
```

or

```
MultivaluedMap queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("resource","193/23";
  ClientResponse response = service.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class));
```

I suggest you consider familiarizing yourself with the [Jax-RS API here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with), it has a nice description of path as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. Could you please tell me for what purpose I should use 'service.path()'?